# SQL Insert Into multiple rows, but execute subquery only once

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, insert-into

Im trying to optimize an INSERT INTO statement to use a subquery only once, as it is always the same value:

Heres my example code

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id, number) VALUES 
((SELECT other_id from TABLE2 WHERE somevalue = "test"), 12),
((SELECT other_id from TABLE2 WHERE somevalue = "test"), 13),
...,
...;
```

Not an sql-expert, but this doesnt look like a good approach, as the same subquery gets executed on every insert.

Is there an alternative solution?

also, i know i can select the ID beforehand and store it in a variable like this (pseudo-code-like):

```
$var = mysql_query("SELECT other_id from TABLE2 WHERE somevalue = 'test'")
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id, number) VALUES 
    ($var, 12),
    ($var, 13);")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT
INTO    table1 (id, number)
SELECT  other_id, number
FROM    table2
CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT  12 number
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  13
        ) q
WHERE   somevalue = 'test'
```

Comment: what if there are more than just 2 values? wouldn't i have to create a huge join table?

Comment: Yes, but those should be quick (as you would just be selecting constants and unioning the results together), while the actual query against data is just performed once. If those numbers are stored in a table (such as if they are the keys to records on another table) then you could join against that table using `IN(13,13)` instead of unioning the constants.